# Cannot see Options Menu on Android Device

Tags: android

I've got an application written with `minSdkVersion="8"` and `targetSdkVersion="19"`, because is so simple and I need it to be used on low level android devices.
The problem is when I try to use it in an Android 4+ device. I cannot see the Options menu.

When I use the app in the Emulator, I use the "Menu" `button`, and I can see it. But not in my tablet or mobile phone (both with 4+ version).

Okay, let's see the code:

In the `manifest.xml` file I have this (I think the problem is the theme...).

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.clv.app2.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme">
```

And I have a simple `OnCreateOptionsMenu` like this in `MainActivity`... (I have defined only two options).

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.option_menu, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Can anyone can help me to see where is the problem with this?

Thank you in advance.

EDIT:

```
option_menu.xml

<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item
    android:id="@+id/scan"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
    android:title="@string/connect"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/discoverable"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_mylocation"
    android:title="@string/discoverable"/>
```

EDIT:
Okay. I have been reading other entries in forum, and I see that there are devices that have not a menu key (to show options menu), and from 3+ version it is not required to have it.
When I execute my application in an Android device less than 3 version, I have that physical button, and it works. In an Android device more than 3 version (I have one with 4+ version), that button does not exists, and there are no way to make the options menu visible.
My question is... Do I have to put a button in screen on 3+ devices with no "physical menu button", to use it when I want to see the options menu???

Comment: what class does MainActivity extends?

Comment: Check if this method for creation of menu is called at all. (In debugger)

Comment: Hello blackbelt.MainActivity extends Activity.

Comment: Make sure you don't hide the actionbar, if you hide actionbar tablet and other devices which shows soft navigation menus won't have option menu. unless until you enable it.

Comment: DjDexter5GHz hello. Yes this method is called. I have debug it and I reach the method. Thank you.

Comment: Emender  hello. No, I don't hide the actionbar. I have made other applications with the same method, and I see the button to display the options menu, but in this case I don't.

Comment: Could we see option_menu.xml?

Comment: eltabo, I have edit my entry, you can see it there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It think the issue is in your activity schema.

First change schema in AndroidManifest to yours:

```
<activity
    android:name="com.clv.app2.MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/MyTheme">
```

Create `styles_mytheme.xml` in `values` folder with lines:

```
<resources>
    <style name="Theme.MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme"/>
</resources>
```

Or just add next line to any styles files:

```
<style name="Theme.MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme"/>
```

Create folder `values-v11` and create file there `styles_mytheme.xml`:

```
<resources>
    <style name="Theme.MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo"/>
</resources>
```

So basically your `Activity` will use default theme for old devices and Holo for devices from v11.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have made the changes you said, and I have execute it in 2+ version device. It works. But when I execute it in 4+ version device, it fails. I get an exception: "You cannot combine custom titles with other title features".... Don't know what more can I do...

Answer (score 1):

I have found the problem that make the application not work on 4+ devices.

In the `onCreate` method I have in my MainActivity, I have this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Log.d(TAG, "En onCreate...");

    // Preparo texto cabecera de pantalla

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE,
            R.layout.custom_title);
```

If I take all that code out, leaving only `setContentView` it works.

Answer (score 0):

I think its not a problem of theme, but while creating your project just make changes like:

- Minimum Required SDK: API8: Android 2.2(Froyo)
- Target SDK: API17:Android 4.2(Jelly Bean)
- Compile With: API8: Android 2.2(Froyo)
- Theme: None

Hope it will work.

Comment: Hello Ganesh. No, this has not work. If I make a new project with that configuration, and no more... and I put it on a 4+ version android device without "menu button", I cannot see the Options Menu... and I have no way to make it visible. If I execute it with the Eclipse debugger, I can use the "Menu button", and it works... Any idea? :)